# Remove row values and convert into single column value

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure returning a table that looks like this:

```
ID | Type | Price | Description
-------------------------------
7  | J    | 50.00 | Job
7  | F    | 20.00 | Freight
7  | P    | 30.00 | Postage
7  | H    |  5.00 | Handling
```

I would like it to return the table like this:

```
ID | Type | Price | Description | FreightPrice
-----------------------------------------
7  | J    | 50.00 | Job         | 20.00
7  | P    | 30.00 | Postage     | 20.00
7  | H    |  5.00 | Handling    | 20.00
```

Is there a way that I can use a query such as:

```
SELECT * FROM Temp WHERE Type = 'F'
```

but return the 'Freight' row as a column instead with just the 'Price' value?

From what I have seen it appears that I may need to use the PIVOT operator to achieve this but that seems overly complex. Is there a way that I could achieve this result using a CASE or IF expression?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the data you provided, there is one row having the description value: "Freight". Assuming this is the case, then try:

```
select ID,Type,Price,Description,
       FreightPrice = (select Price 
                       from mytable 
                       where Description = 'Freight')
from mytable
where Description <> 'Freight'
```

Comment: Yep, we got the same one :) I didn't know you could do `FreightPrice = ...` in SQL Server. Anyway +1

Comment: @TheImpaler there are several ways you can write aliases in sql server. Aaron Bertrand does a great job looking at them [here](https://sqlblog.org/2012/01/23/bad-habits-to-kick-using-as-instead-of-for-column-aliases).

Comment: That did the trick, I was overthinking it apparently. Thank you Eray and Impaler. I will accept this answer since it was first.

Comment: @SeanLange Nice article.

Answer (score 1):

If the `Freight` row is always moved to the right you can hard code this logic (assuming it's always a single row), as in:

```
select
  id,
  type,
  price,
  description,
  (select price from t where description = 'Freight') as freightprice
from t
where description <> 'Freight'
```

**Note:** this query will crash if your table has more than one row for `Freight`.

Comment: Thanks for verifying my answer :)